# append vectors to empty list

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy, append

In a for loop, I read iteratively one vector from file that then I want to put in a list or numpy array. I don't really understand how this process works for numpy arrays or lists. Since I know numpy arrays are not done to change size, I wanted to use an empty list and  iteratively append the vector I'm reading

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1],[2],[3]])
b = np.array([[2],[3],[4]])

c = timeStep = list()

c = c.append(a)
c = c.append(b)
```

The example above describes what I would like to do but, when I print the c list after appending a, the terminal shows there is nothing inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You want to create a list I suggest you to use:

```
c = [] #this is an empty list in Python
```

Now, if You want to append a numpy array in that list, You should use:

```
c.append(YourNumpyArray)
```

Your code should look like this:

```
a = np.array([[1],[2],[3]])
b = np.array([[2],[3],[4]])

c = []

c.append(a)
c.append(b)

print(c)
```

Notice that You don't need to do `c = c.append()`

Answer (score 0):

[image: The output of the python REPL]

As you can see in the figure also, the append doesn't return anything. It appends to the original array `c`. So you are overwriting the appended array with `None`.

This should be the working code for you.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1],[2],[3]])
b = np.array([[2],[3],[4]])

c = timeStep = list()

c.append(a)
c.append(b)
```

On a side note, yes you can use python lists with numpy arrays. If the number of elements in the list `c` is fixed or pre-known, you can make it a numpy array too.